# Problem with accessing table columns from models in search function

Tags: php, laravel

I have a search function that can search users based on filters that user inputs (from/to age, from/to height). Problem is that age column is in users table (User model) and height column is in user_profiles table (UserProfile model). I can get results from each model individually easy but I want to fetch results when I combine those two conditions. For example, fetch users with age 30 to 40 years old that are between 180 cm and 190 cm. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code.

SearchController.php

```
class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function search(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        $query = User::query();   // HERE I NEED TO FETCH USER PROFILE COLUMNS FROM MODEL ALONG WITH USER
        dd($query);

        // HEIGHT SETTING
        if ($request->has('from_cm')) {
            $request->get('from_cm');
        }

        if ($request->has('to_cm')) {
            $request->get('to_cm');
        }

        if ($request->from_cm && $request->to_cm) {
            $query->whereBetween('height', [$request->from_cm, $request->to_cm]);
        } elseif ($request->from_cm) {
            $query->where('height', '>=', $request->from_cm);
        } elseif ($request->to_cm) {
            $query->where('height', '<=', $request->to_cm);
        }

        // AGE SETTING
        if ($request->has('from_age')) {
            $request->get('from_age');
        }

        if ($request->has('to_age')) {
            $request->get('to_age');
        }

        if ($request->from_age && $request->to_age) {
            $query->whereBetween('age', [$request->from_age, $request->to_age]);
        } elseif ($request->from_age) {
            $query->where('age', '>=', $request->from_age);
        } elseif ($request->to_age) {
            $query->where('age', '<=', $request->to_age);
        }

        $results = $query->get();
        //dd($results);
    }
}
```

User.php

```
protected $fillable = [
        'username', 
        'email', 
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'age',
    ];  

public function userProfile()
{
    return $this->hasOne(UserProfile::class);
}
```

UserProfile.php

```
protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'interested_in',
        'height',
      
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

So, to be clear I don't need particular user with his user profile but joined columns from user and user profile models in one variable ($query).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I could understand you need a query similar to:

```
$users = User::with('userProfile')
->whereBetween('age', [$minAge, $maxAge])
->whereHas('userProfile', function($query){
    $query->whereBetween('height', [$minHeight, $maxHeight]);
});
```

This would fetch all users with their profiles where the uer's age is between `$minAge` and `$maxAge` and their profile's height is between `$minHeight` and `$maxHeight`.

**EDIT**

If you want to be able to retrieve the data separately with your filer, then what you'd need are [conditional clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#conditional-clauses). The code would look like that:

```
$users = User::with('userProfile')
->when($ageFilterActive, function($query, $ageFilterActive) {
    $query->whereBetween('age', [$minAge, $maxAge]);
})->when($heightFilterActive, function($query, $heightFilterActive) {
    $query->whereHas('userProfile', function($query){
        $query->whereBetween('height', [$minHeight, $maxHeight]);
    });
});
```

I hope I haven't messed up the syntax, but you get the idea. Alternatively, you can achieve the same with `if-else` statements extending your `$query` variable, but I personally prefer the elegant `when` syntax by Laravel.

Comment: Well I want to be able to fetch them both individually and combined. For example I enter values only for age and then it shows only that, and other example I want age and height comined.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

1. Extract this logic away from the controller and put it in the User model.
2. Since you are using Dependency injection for the user model in the controller you may do something like this in the controller

`$user->filter($request->input('min_height'),$request->input('max_height'),$request->input('min_age'),$request->input('max_age'));`

This way the controller will be responsible to pass the needed data to the model and from there you can do the query inside of the model.

The benefit of this is

1. More clear controllers
2. The controller will take care only of taking the request, pass the needed data and pass the result to the index.
3. You can reuse this filter anywhere as long as you have the user instance
4. The responsability will be splited between the model and the controller and the controller wont be doing everything

**In your User model the query will be something like this:**

```
public function scopeWithUserProfile($query)
{
    // Left join or inner join depends on your needs
    return $query->join('user_profile', 'users.id', '=', 'user_profile.user_id');
}

public function filter($minHeight, $maxHeight, $minAge, $maxAge) {
    $query = $this->query()
        ->withUserProfile();
    
    if (!is_null($minHeight) && !is_null($maxHeight)) {
        $query->whereBetween('height', [$minHeight, $maxHeight]);
    }
    
    if (!is_null($minAge) && !is_null($maxAge)) {
        $query->whereBetween('age', [$minAge, $maxAge]);
    }
    
    return $query;
}
```

1. The reason that we are returning instance of eloquent and we are not doing
   `$query->get()` is that this way we can do it in the controller and for every place that
   we are reusing this code we can do things like `orderBy`, `groupBy`, `first`, `get` and other things depending on the needs of the place that we are calling it at. Because if you do a `$query->get()` you will be limited with the `Collection` only.
2. After that we can do something like this in the controller `$query->get()` and from there we will have the collection of the needed data.

In the controller at the end you must have something like this

```
public function search(Request $request, User $user)
{
    $user->filter($request->input('min_height'),$request->input('max_height'),$request->input('min_age'),$request->input('max_age'));
    
    return view('your.view.here', [
        'userData' => $user->get(),
    ]);
}
```

I don't know if the explanation is clear enough but I will be more than happy to answer any question that you have as long as I can :P

I hope the syntax is okey, but you can achieve your needs by adding more If and else statements to filter them as needed.